# How can I avoid control character interpretation in Javascript template string interpolation?

Tags: javascript, string, newline, template-strings

I have a string variable containing a control character (newline). I want to output that variable but with the control character as its literal representation and not interpreted:

```js
console.log(`Using "${nl}" as newline`)
```

where the `nl` variable may contain one of `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n`.
The output of this is of course

> Using
> as newline

but it should be e.g.

> Using "\r\n" as newline

I guess I somehow need to construct a string like this

```js
console.log('Using "\\r\\n" as newline')
```

So I've been trying to escape the backslashes in `nl` by prepending another backslash using `nl.replace()` but that doesn't seem to work because the `nl` variable doesn't actually contain any backslash characters.

Is there a way to do this generically, i.e. without coding explicitly for `\n`, `\r`, and `\r\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the double quotes, and use `JSON.stringify` which also produces those quotes, and which encodes newline characters (and more, such as TAB, BS, FF, and escapes double quote and backslash):

```js
let nl = "\r\n";
console.log(`Using ${JSON.stringify(nl)} as newline`);

// Or with a newline in a template literal:

nl = `
`;
console.log(`Using ${JSON.stringify(nl)} as newline`);
```